# JSON response format when modifying user during beforeCreate blocking function (Google Identity Platform)

Tags: node.js, go, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the Go runtime in a beforeCreate blocking function to modify newly created users in Google Identity Platform. So far I've parsed and validated the JWT and I'm able to block or allow the user signup, but I don't know what JSON response Google expects when modifying the user being processed.

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions#modifying_a_user) are written exclusively for developers using the Node.js SDK, and don't mention the expected JSON response when implementing the same using the Go runtime. I tried using `{"disabled":"true"}` in my JSON response, but that doesn't work outside the NodeJS SDK. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full JSON response schema to modify a user before creation is as follows:

```
{
  "userRecord": {
    "updateMask": "customClaims,disabled,displayName,emailVerified,photoUrl",
    "customClaims": {
      "exampleRole": "ExampleUserRole",
      "otherExampleClaim": "ExampleUserClaim2",
      "otherExampleUserProperty": "ExampleUserClaim3"
    },
    "disabled": true,
    "displayName": "Example Name",
    "emailVerified": false,
    "photoUrl": "https://localhost/image.jpg"
  }
}
```

To disable a new user for example:

```
{
  "userRecord": {
    "updateMask": "disabled",
    "disabled": true
  }
}
```